# No se puede acceder a archivo php, por que no se encuentra definida una variable

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una lista de planillas que para acceder a cada una de ellas necesitas que sea mediante el click de un botón con código JS.

---

Formulario de lista en HTML:

```
<form name="acciones_consultar_omd_unidades" id="acciones_consultar_omd_unidades" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="campo_verificador" name="campo_verificador" value="" hidden>
<input type="text" id="id_omd" name="id_omd" value="" hidden>
<td bgcolor= "#e4f1f6" width="25"><center><a href="javascript:enviame('planilla_omd.php', '<?=$omd?>')"> Ver </a></center></td></tr>
```

Esto lo hago para evitar que puedan acceder metiendo el ID en la URL.

---

La función `enviame` es la siguiente:

```
function enviame(planillaurl, omd){

      //añado el url del action al formulario
      var formulario =document.getElementById("acciones_consultar_omd_unidades");
      formulario.action=planillaurl;

      //Agrego a ID el valor del ID que se selecciono
      var omdcampo=document.getElementById("id_omd");
      omdcampo.value=omd;

      //Agrego el valor de 1 al consultado
      var campo_verificador=document.getElementById("campo_verificador");
      campo_verificador.value=1;

      //Envio el formulario = acciones_consultar_omd_unidades action=planilla_omd.php?id_omd=
      formulario.submit();
}
```

Lo que hago es asignarle al action el valor de la ID que se va a consultar para que pueda ser POSTEADO.

---

Una vez validada la consulta te pasara al siguiente codigo, donde hace el post del campo verificador.

Planilla.php:

```
$ver_omd= $_POST["campo_verificador"];

if ($ver_omd == 1 || $ver_omd == 2)
  {
  require_once '__conexion.php';
  require_once '__conexion2.php';
  }
  else
  {
  echo ('<script>alert("No tiene permisos suficientes para acceder a esta parte del sistema");</script>');
  echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
  }
```

---

**El problema es que esto funciona para ver las planillas dentro de la lista, pero NO para el proceso de generar nuevos registros.**

---

Cuando terminas de hacer un nuevo registro habrá un boton JS que te redirecciona asi:

generar.js

```
   var agree=confirm("\u00BFEsta seguro que desea generar esta OMD?.");
   if (agree){
   document.getElementById("generando").value = 1;
   document.omd.submit();
   return true ;
   }
   else
   return false ;
```

generar.php

```
$generando = $_POST["generando"];
session_start();

if ($generando == 1)
  {
  require_once '__conexion.php';
  }
  else
  {
  echo ('<script>alert("No tiene permisos suficientes para acceder a esta parte del sistema");</script>');
  echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
  }
$id_omd = $stmt->insert_id; // <-- AQUI obtenemos el ID
echo ("<script>window.location = 'planilla_omd.php?omd=$id_omd';</script>");
```

---

El proceso en conclusion:

- Lleno el formulario de datos.
- Pulso el boton js y este pone 1 en generando.
- Entro a generar.php y si generando es 1 pasa a realizar la sentencia SQL.
- Termina la sentencia y te redirecciona a planilla_omd.

**Cuando generas una planilla solo te manda por URL el omd y no el campo verificador, como puedo hacer para que se manden esos dos datos y pueda asi pasar la verificacion del If?**

Comment: En qué momento de tu proceso quieres mandar el campo verificador? Es decir en qué archivo?

Comment: @Lixus que lo pasara desde generar.php para que lo reconozca planilla.php con esto: $ver_omd= $_POST["campo_verificador"];

Comment: En planilla.php cuando recibes la forma, debes de poder obtener el valor de la variable `$_POST['campo_verificador']` no?

Comment: @Lixus si lo recibe, el problema es que cuando lo hace es porque fue enviado por el enviame.js, PERO cuando genero la planilla este no se envia asi, solo se hace un window.location

Comment: Y ese generado de planilla que es por window.location en donde está, en generar.php? Y a generar.php en qué momoento de tu proceso accedes a el?

Comment: el generado ocurre con genera.pho  lo termina de llenar y el hace esto: echo ("<script>window.location = 'planilla_omd.php?omd=$id_omd';</script>"); a genera.php se accede mediante el llenado de un formulario

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58065/discussion-between-lixus-and-victor-random).

Comment: Y en generar .php recibes también la variable `$_POST['campo_verificador']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifique el enviame.js:

```
function enviame3(planillaurl, omd){

      //añado el url del action al formulario
      var formulario =document.getElementById("acciones_generar_omd_unidades");
      formulario.action=planillaurl;

      //Agrego a ID el valor del ID que se selecciono
      var omdcampo=document.getElementById("id_omd");
      omdcampo.value=omd;

      //Agrego el valor de 1 al consultado
      var campo_verificador=document.getElementById("campo_verificador");
      campo_verificador.value=1;

      //Envio el formulario = acciones_consultar_omd_unidades action=planilla_omd.php?id_omd=
      formulario.submit();
}
```

Y agregue codigo HTML en generar.php

```
if ($stmt->execute())
  {
  $id_omd = $stmt->insert_id; // <-- AQUI obtenemos el ID
?>
<html>
        <script src="funciones/validarFormularios.js"></script>
        <body onload="enviame3('planilla_omd.php', '<?=$id_omd?>')">
        <form name="acciones_generar_omd_unidades" id="acciones_generar_omd_unidades" method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" id="campo_verificador" name="campo_verificador" value="">
        <input type="text" id="id_omd" name="id_omd" value="">
 </html>
<?php
 $stmt->close();
  }
}
  else
  {
  echo ('<script>alert("No se pudo generar la OMD");</script>');
  echo ("<script>window.location = 'menu_generar_omd_unidades.php';</script>");
  }
?>
```